# Google App Engine cannot serve some of mp4 files

Tags: google-app-engine, video, blobstore

I uploaded 2 .mp4 videointo blobstore.
When I served 311.0KB mp4 video, there is no problem with it. I can play the video
But when I served 3.3MB mp4 video, video is not loaded. So I went to admin console, and click Blob Viewer menu. When I clicked to see 3.3MB video, it doesn't load as well. Why?

I am using free version of GAE.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: I used to have problems with serving video files from blobstore. The method I used was to set the X-AppEngine-BlobKey header in the response. This method sometimes uses Transfer-coding chunked. However it generates problems with serving mp4 files. I had problems on IE actually. What I did to solve the problem was to implement serving files using 206 response code and byte ranges and to make sure that Cache-control header is not set for mp4 files. This of course won't solve the admin console problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I found out that using the X-AppEngine-BlobKey and X-AppEngine-BlobRange is working fine. I use Django and here is part of the code that I use, it should give you the idea how it works

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
response['Content-Type'] = content_type
response['X-AppEngine-BlobKey'] = blob_key
if 'HTTP_RANGE' in request.META:
    response['X-AppEngine-BlobRange'] = request.META['HTTP_RANGE']
return response
```

Please note that X-AppEngine-BlobRange is set to exactly the same value as range header in request. GAE documentation for that case might be a little bit confusing as the examples show values like "0-499" when it should be set to "bytes=0-499".